# How to define a Logic-App response based on the user making the request

Tags: azure, http, authorization, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to develop a simple HTTP request response logic app which is pretty straight forward. The complexity I’m now facing is – how do I go about returning different bits of data from the same api call based on the user making the request? Any architectural suggestions would be appreciated.

Note: Mutliple users will be calling the app (power and none-power users)

**User 1 making a request would get:**

```
{
   "UserDetails":{
      "Name":"John",
      "Age":30
   }
}
```

**User 2 (power user) making the same request would get:**

```
{
   "UserDetails":{
      "Name":"John",
      "Age":"30",
      "Account":{
         "Reg Number":123
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Whether it is possible to add a parameter after the URL to judge its users, if so, use `condition` to judge it.

Comment: Not sure this soultion would be feasible. I would end up with a lot of conditional ckecks for each user. I'll update the initial question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

To serve this purpose, you can create Http Request Triggered Logic App with input payload structure defined, something like below example:

[image]

- Read `UserType` using the payload and add a `Condition` Action method in the Logic App as depicted in an example below:

  [image]
- Add a check for `UserType` value, if the `UserType` is normal user, generate a response (using `Compose` Action) and send back to the user using `Response` Action as depicted in an example below:

  [image]
- Send a response accordingly in the case when `UserType` is power user (using `Compose` Action  as depicted in an example below):

  [image]